# Wordpress + filter post by name

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

Is there a function in wordpress to iterate through all posts and discard posts with same name?  E.g. I have several posts named "Banana" and I need just one post with that name to be shown?

It's actually custom post type and I am using WP_Query to query posts ?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a function. But you could easily add this functionality to a vanilla `WP_Query` loop. Here's one solution that uses an array to "remember" post names during iteration:

```
<?php

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // an array to remember titles
    $titles = array()

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $the_title = get_the_title(); // (1) grab the current post title
        if ($titles[$the_title]) continue; // (2) duplicate title: skip post!
        $titles[$the_title] = TRUE; // (3) otherwise, remember the title

        // ..do post stuff..

    endwhile;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

The lookup for (2) is fast because `Array` is implemented as a map in PHP. See [Arrays](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more info.

Comment: Excellent idea. I used something similar... I just placed everything into arrays and than compared arrays to exclude duplicates (my project was bit more complicated than I described, but you gave me an idea how to solve it). Thanks mate !